# How to design a class holding information about a relationship between two interchangable objects

Tags: c#, design, object-oriented

I'd like to design a class that holds comparison results about to objects.

Given I have a class `Thing` and that `Thing` has a bunch of properties. Now I have an engine that compares `Thing` instances (held in a collection) to one another. Comparisons are actually Types deriving from a `Comparison` base class and can be fairly complex (e.g. ColorComparison). The actual result is not of importance, only that the comparison results in a match. So if comparing two `Thing` instances succeeds the comparison will be stored in a `Match` class, along with information about the applied comparison. So a `Match` class might have the properties

- ThingA
- ThingB
- Comparison

I later need to store the `Match` class instances in a HashSet for fast lookup. What identifies a `Match` is the combination of ThingA and ThingB. In a perfect world the `Match` class could provide the same Hash for ThingA = x and ThingB = y vs. ThingA = y and ThingB = x. It might be later needed that not only one Comparison is stored within a Match but several different.

Some additional implementation notes:

- Once a `Match` class has been instanciated, both ThingA and ThingB are immutable
- The Things inside a `Match` cannot be manipulated (e.g. I cannot store the relationship information inside them)

My question is, how to I design the `Match` class in a way that when the HashSet is searched for the x and y combination of `Thing`s it also finds the y and x combination.

Comment: @DocBrown Thanks for pointing out what is unclear about my question. It's kind of tough because English is not my mother tongue. I updated the question and hope it's clearer now.

Comment: `In a perfect world the Match class could provide the same Hash for ThingA = x and ThingB = y vs. ThingA = y and ThingB = x` - Isn't that your answer right there? Is there a reason you can't just define your equals and hash code that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just define `hash()` and `equals()` for `Match` such that it is independent of the ordering of `thingA` and `thingB`.

This can be done like so (pseudo-python):

```
class Match:
    def hash(self, other):
        return self.thingA.hash() + self.thingB.hash() + self.comparison.hash()

    def equals(self, other):
        if self.comparison != other.comparison:
            return False
        if self.thingA == other.thingA and self.thingB == other.thingB:
            return True
        return self.thingA == other.thingB  and self.thingB == other.thingA
```